# How to change mountpoint name?

Tags: mount, directory

This question has been asked before, but because I have a few more doubts about the process.

I am working in ubuntu, this is what `df -h` shows:

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0               423G  337G   65G  84% /
tmpfs                   12G     0   12G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                    12G  188K   12G   1% /dev
tmpfs                   12G     0   12G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md1               917G  527G  344G  61% /backup
```

The problem is that now we are using the /dev/md1 for more than just backups, and we have decided to change its name from /backup to /drive2

I want all the content to stay where it is, the only thing that has to change is the name of the drive mountpoint.

Please note however that I have certain symbolic links from the /dev/md0 to the /dev/md1, and they where built using /backup as a reference folder. Will I have to change each symbolic link or will the change be reflected automatically?

Could you please explain the commands necessary and the files to edit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change the mountpoint name all your symlinks will break. Here are 2 options you can use:

**Option 1**

- Edit the mountpoint name in `/etc/fstab` to the desired new mountpoint
- To ensure the symlinks keep working, make `/backup` a symlink to the new mountpoint:

  ```
  ln -s /new/mountpoint /backup
  ```

**Option 2**

- Use a [bind mount](http://docs.1h.com/Bind_mounts) to specify an alternative mountpoint for your RAID array while keeping the existing `/backup` mounted.
- To do this from `/etc/fstab`, you need to specify `bind` as the filesystem type and add it to the list of options as well. See [this LinuxQuestions Q&A](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/mount-bind-fstab-problem-383883/)

Note that the second option is Linux-specific.

**Edit**

**Thoughts on option 1**

- Since `/backup` is currently a mountpoint, you'll need to delete it first so it can be recreated as a symlink. Be *very careful* to unmount it first as you don't want to delete the actual contents of your partition: only the mountpoint directory.
- To be extra safe, when deleting `/backup`, use `rmdir` instead of `rm`. I learned this very useful usage of `rmdir` the hard way :(

**Thoughts on option 2**

- This option is a bit more complicated *and* is specific to Linux. There may be a reason you might prefer it, though. If you go with option 1, anything that once depended on `/backup` being a mountpoint (i.e. on `mountpoint /backup` returning true) will break.